# un uso correcto de las funciones y objetos

Tags: php, mysql, poo

Tengo una duda, si esta forma de uso es correcta, nunca he creado una web de 0  y no sé si este uso de los objetos es correcto

Tengo esta función, que me saca un formulario hecho por el eco, con los datos a modificar.

```
public function modificarUsuario($nia){

            $sql = "SELECT nia,nombre,apellidos,email,telefono,especialidad_estudio FROM usuario WHERE nia = ?";

                        $this->nia=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($nia));

                        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
                        $stmt->bind_param('i',$nia);
                        $stmt->execute();       
                        $stmt->bind_result($nia,$nombre,$apellidos,$email,$telefono,$especialidad_estudio);

                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    echo "<form action='actualizar.php' method='POST'>
                          <input type='text'  name='nia' value=$nia><br>
                          <input type='text'  name='nombre' value=$nombre><br>
                          <input type='text'  name='apellidos' value=$apellidos><br>
                          <input type='text'  name='email' value=$email><br>
                          <input type='text'  name='telefono' value=$telefono><br>

                          <label for='estudios'>Escoge tus estudios:</label>
                          <select name='estudios'>
                            <option value='daw'>Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Web</option>
                            <option value='dam'>Desarrollo de Aplicaciones Multiplataforma</option>
                            <option value='administracion'>Administración y Finanzas</option>
                            <option value='sonido'>Técnico Superior en Sonido</option>
                          </select>
                          <input type='submit' value='Registrarse'>
                          </form>";

                }

                $stmt->close();
                $this->conn->close();           
             }
```

Esta es la función que hace el update (Todavía me queda parametrizar, pero quería probar)

```
 public function Actualizar($nia,$nombre,$apellidos,$email,$telefono,$especialidad){


                 $sql = "UPDATE usuario SET nia = $nia , nombre = '$nombre' , apellidos = '$apellidos' , email = '$email', telefono = $telefono 
                         , especialidad_estudio='$especialidad'  WHERE nia=$nia";

                   $this->conn->query($sql);
                   $this->conn->close();    

              }
            }
```

Y esta página es la que veria la página del usuario, mi duda es esta, si ese pequeño código de php con el objeto, es correcta o no.

```
<?php 

    require_once('Usuario.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>ACTUALIZAR USUARIO</h1>

        <?php
           $usuario = new Usuario();
           $usuario->modificarUsuario(2525);
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Espero que se me entienda,gracias

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿ Obtienes el resultado que esperas o no lo obtienes ? Si lo obtienes, es correcto. Si no lo obtienes ... pues reformula la pregunta :-)

Comment: Obtener lo obtengo,  y funciona perfectamente, pero mi duda es si esa forma es correcta o si debería hacerla de otra manera,ya que  hay veces que te da el resultado que quieres, pero la manera de hacerlo  no es las correcta del todo.

Comment: Eso sería basado en opiniones y generará el cierre de tu pregunta